# Firefox ignores font in print preview - font doesn't work

Tags: css, firefox, printing, fonts, print-preview

I've the following problem: I use a special font which is installed on my system. It works fine on my `screen`-view but in the `print preview` Firefox just uses my standard font.

As I said the font is installed and I'm not using any fancy `CSS3` tricks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a frustrating day searching the internet and rewriting my code I finally found the answer! You need to disable Firefox' `hardware acceleration`!

Just follow these steps:

```
Tools > Options > Advanced > General Tab > Disable hardware acceleration
Restart Firefox
```

I found it on [this page](http://www.favbrowser.com/firefox-ignores-font-family/).